# URL End line has %20 and %3f characters and escape fragment in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I got the following URL

```
http://www.test.com/News/-News-mainnews-detail_42.html%E2%80%9D%20target=
```

and

```
 http://www.local.com/News/News_mainnews_83.html%20
```

I have added following line in web.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
```

this one working in my local. but could nor run in Live. It returs `Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.`

Is there any solution to be run in live?

Comment: i think your `News` action must decode the strings that it gets as parameter

Comment: now it came again and again and I have redirected some pages, but its not possible all the time